# Racket's syntax-parse: identifier not matching as expected

Tags: parsing, scheme, racket

I'm having trouble with Racket's `syntax-parse`. In particular, I am getting the following error message:

```
unknown: rule: expected one of these identifiers: `model', `line', or `rule'
at: rule
in: (rule (predicate (symbol "T") "[" (symbol-list (symbol "X")) "]") "<-" (predicate (symbol "Q") "[" (symbol-list (symbol "X")) "]"))
```

Why isn't the `rule` syntax object matching the identifier? I'm invoking the function as follows:

```
(define (parse-carl s)
(syntax-parse s
    [((~literal model) ~rest x)
        (with-syntax ([x (map parse-carl (syntax-e #'x))]) #'x)]
    [((~literal line) x) (with-syntax ([x (parse-carl #'x)]) #'x)]
    [((~literal rule) p1 "<-" p2) 'ok]))
```

Here is the input (passed through `syntax->datum`):

```
(model (line (rule (predicate (symbol T) [ (symbol-list (symbol X)) ]) <- (predicate (symbol Q) [ (symbol-list (symbol X)) ]))) 
(line (rule (predicate (symbol Y) [ (symbol-list (symbol X)) ]) <-   (predicate (symbol Q) [ (symbol-list (symbol X)) ]))) 
(line (rule (predicate (symbol Y) [ (symbol-list (symbol X)) ]) <- (predicate (symbol T) [ (symbol-list (symbol X)) ]))) 
(line (query (rule (predicate (symbol Y) [ (symbol-list (symbol X)) ]) <- (predicate (symbol T) [ (symbol-list (symbol X)) ])) ?)) 
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include the expression, that led to your error message.

Comment: Actually, include the whole program if possible...

Comment: I've updated the post.

Comment: The question is, is `rule` actually defined? `~literal` recognizes a binding, so if there's no binding, it won't work. You would need `~datum` instead in that case.

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase Thanks, that is exactly the problem. Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `rule` actually defined? `~literal` recognizes a binding, so if there's no binding, it won't work. You would need `~datum` instead in that case.